# Android GCM messages sending Not receiving

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android GCM service I am sending the message with PHP i got
as a response

```
{"multicast_id":5035179847798608085,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1399447523487490%5695579af9fd7ecd"}]}
```

it look like it dose send it but not receiving in on my android app

here is my PHP code :

```
     $registrationId="APA91bHx1bvBURGF4YSMDWGd5fPb33YtWfwEDspbsT-ejAYR0K_rao7NCSUtki7bP_1BvoCWn8fNpqAIPSjchvcy2JGtdJPvVC85cU9fhFoiE-Cos7PyhUhqIkpXznrD2rNhg9sVlWF2J5c9vSLLHP0LJDq5Q5M29dnUGzaROWcGBqsw3673VKM";
    // API access key from Google API's Console

    // Message to send
    $message      = "the test message";
    $tickerText   = "ticker text message";
    $contentTitle = "content title";
    $contentText  = "content body";

    //$registrationId = 'DEVICE_ID';
    $apiKey = "AIzaSyBx6hRnATNJGeYqeF4fzZLrNriuV2TRacI";

    $response = sendNotification(
        $apiKey,
        $registrationId,
        array('message' => $message, 'tickerText' => $tickerText, 'contentTitle' => $contentTitle, "contentText" => $contentText)
    );


    echo $response;




      $data = array(
            'data'=>$messageData,
            'registration_ids' => array($registrationIds)

        );


        var_dump( $headers);
        var_dump ($data);
        $ch = curl_init();
        $data= json_encode($data);

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );

        var_dump ($data);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }
```

Need help

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a Wifi network. The firewall must allow 5228 open found on [Gcm config](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html) 
You can use a tool to help the check the connection [GCM Server for windows](https://gcm.codeplex.com/)